# Getting devices with custom system app

Tags: system-apps

So, I am looking into getting devices with a custom app pre-installed from factory on the system image in a "device as a service" scenario. I am specifically interested in the app having system privileges without rooting the device. From some initial research, I believe solutions like Knox (MDMs) would not be able to cover this. What kind of solution would this be? What is the correct industry terminology here?

Comment: The device manufacturer will welcome you if you are a mobile network provider or another bigger company with 30k+ customers and may be order a few thousand branded devices for a lot of money.

Comment: @Robert, So what I'm really looking for at this point is custom device manufacturing?